# lock preferences in firefox 45.5 on RHEL

Tags: linux, security, firefox

I am required to make a custom FireFox profile on a RHEL based system. 
most of the configuration are changed inside the FireFox inside the about:config menu. 

When I try and lock parameter values using the "mozilla.cfg" file and the "lockPref("", )" function the browser doesn't seem to read those files, I place the file both in: "~/.mozilla/firefox/" and "/usr/lib64/firefox/". I used the http://kb.mozillazine.org/Lock_Prefs guide and some more and still I have no one answer about where those function should be written and how do I check that those functions were loaded.

 I would like some clear instructions or a definitive guide that I just couldn't manage to find.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This came up fairly high in a Google search when I was asking the same question, but did not have an answer at the time.

I found the following reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment

On RHEL7, the files needed to be added to the following locations:
/usr/lib64/firefox/defaults/preferences/autoconfig.js (root:root, 644)
/usr/lib64/firefox/mozilla.cfg (root:root, 644)